# Apply function to each element in tuple, cast each to a different type in a type pack, then pass as parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-functions

I am building a complex extensible system. The details are not important, but I really like the design except for this one issue.

I have an interface `WithState<T> : Subject` for some type T.

The problematic class is templated on `template <typename... StateTypes>`.

It holds an `std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<WithState<StateTypes>>...>>`.

I have a function `std::any getStateFor(std::shared_ptr<Subject>)` (where `WithState<T> : Subject`).

I also have a function `void handleStates(StateTypes... states)` (might as well take a tuple at this point, whatever is easier)

Now I need to plug all these parts together: I need to upcast the elements in my tuple to `shared_ptr<Subject>`, then apply `getStateFor` to each of these elements in order and `std::any_cast` the results in order of `StateTypes...`, then forward all these at once as a parameter pack to `handleStates`.

(Before this is marked as XY problem: the higher levels of abstractions do not care about concrete state types, whereas I want to implement the lower parts with as much type safety as possible. So far, this approach is looking good for my needs)

I might be able to do this by converting my tuple to a vector, applying `getStateFor` on each, then writing a recursive function which applies the proper `any_cast`, but then I still have no idea how to collect my results into a tuple with different types. I wonder if this works with a smart fold expression...

Here is a skeleton of the existing code:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

// ignoring references and const for brevity

class Subject { 
public:
  /* deleted copy assignment and constructor */ 
  // this is here so that the example works
  virtual std::any getState() = 0;
};

template <typename T> class WithState : public Subject { };

template <typename... StateTypes>
class StateHandler {
public:   
  std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<WithState<StateTypes>>...> subjects;
  // this one is actually in another class, but it doesn't matter
  void handleStates(StateTypes... states);

  void handleStatesForSubjects(std::function<std::any (std::shared_ptr<Subject>)> getStateFor) {
    // how do I implement this?
  }
};

int main() {
  struct foo { int a; int b; };

  struct WithInt : public WithState<int> { 
    std::any getState() override { return 17; } 
  };
  struct WithFoo : public WithState<foo> {
    std::any getState() override { return foo { 1, 2 }; }
  };

  StateHandler<int, foo> handler;

  handler.subjects = { 
    std::make_shared<WithInt>(), std::make_shared<WithFoo>() };

  handler.handleStatesForSubjects([](auto subj) { return subj->getState(); });
}
```

[on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cBU8_Q)

However, this is still missing the `std::any_cast`s to the concrete types.

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be easier for us to work with if you provided a skeleton of the involved types. As it stands, anyone wanting to answer this question is going to have to build this by hand. We are all programmers, so if you want to communicate what the code does, just show code. Don't try to explain it.

Comment: "*I need to upcast the elements in my tuple to shared_ptr<Subject>, then apply getStateFor to each of these elements in order and std::any_cast the results in order of StateTypes..., then forward all these at once as a parameter pack to handleStates.*" Why do you need to use a roundabout way to do this? If you have `StateTypes`, then you know  what types these things contain. So why the conversion to base classes? If they've been converted to base classes, why not convert them back to the derived classes with `StateTypes`? Why use this `any` approach when you *know* the types?

Comment: @NicolBolas I added a code skeleton which might help. The point is that I get the `handleState` function from a higher, more dynamic level of abstraction (which again gets it from a lower level at another point). The whole design needs a paper, which I haven't written yet. But a simpler version in C# works in production, so I know that I'm on the right track.

Comment: And `struct foo { int a, int b };` is missing a semicolon after `b`. I recommend https://godbolt.org (or other online compilers) to quickly check whether your code actually compiles. Anyone trying to answer this will probably paste it in there as a first step, so if that gives no errors your question is off to a good start.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thanks for the hint, I edited the code and added a godbolt link.

Comment: @Dracam Awesome, have an upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your tuple contains `std::shared_ptr<WithState<StateTypes>>...`  so that's what `apply` will try to call your given lambda with, but the lambda only takes `StateTypes&&...`.

There are a few more changes to make it work, but first off the working thing:

https://godbolt.org/z/hyFBtV

- I changed `getStateFor` to be a template function where you specify the type you expect:

  ```
  template<class StateType>
  StateType getStateFor(std::shared_ptr<Subject> s)
  {
      if (auto withState = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<WithState<StateType>>(s))
          return withState->getValue();
      throw "AHHH";
  }
  ```

  You can still assign that to a `std::any` if you want (or provide a non-templated overload that returns `std::any`). But for the purposes here casting to `std::any` and back is just unnecessary overhead - if anything, it's *less* type-safe.
- Your lambda arguments were `StateTypes&&... withStates`. Aside from the type itself needing to be different, the `&&` doesn't work unless you actually provide temporaries to the lambda (which `std::apply` won't do), or if you do type deduction via `auto&&` (which is different). In the code the lambda expression is thus (I took by value for simplicity, you might take by [const] reference):

  ```
      [this](std::shared_ptr<WithState<StateTypes>>... withStatePtrs) {
          handleStates(getStateFor<StateTypes>(withStatePtrs)...);
      }
  ```
- You also don't need a `dynamic_pointer_cast` to go from `std::shared_ptr<WithState<T>>` to `std::shared_ptr<Subject>`.
- Your tuple type had an extra `>`.

---

Edit: Using the snippet in the updated question, you get this:

https://godbolt.org/z/D_AJ1n

The same considerations still apply, you just have to put an `any_cast` in there:

```
void handleStatesForSubjects(std::function<std::any(std::shared_ptr<Subject>)> getStateFor)
{
  std::apply(
    [this, getStateFor](std::shared_ptr<WithState<StateTypes>>... withStates) {
      handleStates(std::any_cast<StateTypes>(getStateFor(withStates))...);
    },
    subjects
  );
}
```

It's probably more straightforward than you expected, but you just write down the operation for each element: Call `getStateFor`, then `any_cast` it. Repeat for each variadic argument (`...`). You don't need any `dynamic_pointer_cast` or similar - `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: sadly, `getStateFor` comes from a higher level of abstraction, which manages many of the `StateHandler`s with partially overlapping types dynamically. So I cannot template it. I still appreciate your insights on my approach.

Comment: @Dracam That shouldn't really be a problem from what I can tell. It's just a lot more pointless casting. Working on applying this to your code sample.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still confused by how the `...` exactly works, especially since it expends on types and values here, at once. But it makes sense when looking at your solution.

Comment: @Dracam I'm still on the fence about `std::any` but I guess it won't be more expensive than a `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to derived (that's basically how `std::any` works in the first place, which is why this is a weird mix). Do note that in isolation, this problem can be solved without any `std::any`, common `Subject` base class or other form of type erasure (and will thus perform much better, in case that's ever of relevance): https://godbolt.org/z/cAoioW

Comment: Note: The mixing of type and value expansion works because you spell out the argument list of the lambda (you don't deduce it again). But if you don't have to manually cast back to the un-erased type, you don't need to expand both types and values (see last link). This means you can conveniently write `auto&&` (to not spell out the long type). It will deduce another variadic pack (from the tuple) which you would not be able to mix with the one from the class, but you don't have to there (you only need to expand the values). It's ok if this doesn't make sense for now but maybe it helps a bit.

Comment: (But you could just spell out the types as in the answer, that works just fine. Just pointing out why writing `auto&&` _wouldn't_ work in the answer - you'd deduce two conceptually different packs that you can't simply expand at the same time).

Comment: Thank you for the additional discussion. It shows that there is always a more elegant solution. Except in this case - the level from where `getStateFor` comes from is very dynamic during runtime. And that is something you always pay for in performance. In this case, I will most likely end up redirecting to a hashmap lookup. But I am glad to know that there are always ways to further optimize.